# How can I protect access to an API without having tokens/passwords on the URL?

Tags: api, security, rest

I have made an RESTful API to my SaaS site.

To use it, users have to input a token key as an argument in the URL.

Even though it's under SSL, I don't like the fact that the key goes in the URL.

What are other ways to secure an API?

Comment: Basically your other option is to send a HMAC of the request together with the request itself, plus a (non-secret) field that lets the server know who the request issuer claims to be; look at how OAuth works.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to send the token in an HTTP header, not the URI. You should use the `Authorization` header itself to keep it standard. When you need to send a token and not a user/password, use a custom realm.

For instance, you can use something like:

```
Authorization: MyCompanyLogin apikey="8hj34893u32j9023r02r"
```